# Getting promise from a nested forEach loop?

Tags: typescript, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to loop through a Firebase List (using AngularFire2), and I want to get a Promise to indicate when the nested loops completed so I can process on the second action. I'm using the following code:

```
  console.log('START');
  this.af.database.list('Sites/123123/Users')
    .map(users => {
      users.map(user => {
        console.log('found a user ', user);
        this.af.database.list('registeredUsers/' + user.$key + '/Sites')
          .forEach(sites => {
            sites.forEach(site => {

              if (site.$value == '123123') {
                console.log('found site ', site.$key);
              }
            });
          });
      });
    }).first().toPromise().then(function (x) {
      console.log('ALL DONE')
    });
```

The output is:

[image: console output]

But I'm getting the Promise only after the outer loop, without waiting for the nested loop to complete. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are creating multiple promises with your `.map()` loops, then you will need to use `Promise.all()` to wait on them.  `Promise.all()` creates a single promise (that you can return) that waits on an array of promises.

Comment: where to put the Promise.all() !?

Comment: I don't know your database interface, but presumably `this.af.database.list()` is async and you need to get a promise from that and return it from your `.map()`.  That means `.map()` will produce an array of promises, which you need to use `Promise.all()` on the array of promises so you can return the single master promise that `Promise.all()` creates.

Comment: can you give me an example ? i tried before using promises array but also didnt work

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how your database produces promises to give you a specific example.  You can read about `Promise.all()` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and many other places on the web.  The concept is that you use something like `.map()` to produce an array of promises and you then call `Promise.all()` on that array of promises to wait for all of them to be done and to collect all the results into a single array.

Comment: If you can point me to the place in your database's doc where it discussed how to get a promise back from `.list()`, then I could probably help you more specifically.

Comment: its Firebase , am using Angularfire2 to retrieve the list

Comment: Like, I said, point me to relevant doc for how to use promises with `.list()` (which I assume is an async operation) and perhaps I can help.  If you can't go that path, then you'll have to wait for someone who already knows Angularfire2 and firebase.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing return statements in the map calls, because you are generating new Observables inside the first map on the users observable you should use a mergeMap here:

```
console.log('START');
this.af.database
    .list('Sites/123123/Users')
    .mergeMap(users => {
        return users.map(user => {
            console.log('found a user ', user);
            return this.af.database.list('registeredUsers/' + user.$key + '/Sites')
                .forEach(sites => {
                    sites.forEach(site => {
                        if (site.$value == '123123') {
                            console.log('found site ', site.$key);
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    })
    .first().toPromise().then(x => {
        console.log('ALL DONE')
    });
```

Here I have a simplified version of your code, eliminating dependencies to your firebase app:

```js
//const Rx =  require('rxjs'); // require Rx on nodejs instead of html script tag
const usersObservable = Rx.Observable.from([[{ id: 1, $key: 123 }]]);

const sitesObservable = Rx.Observable.from(
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve([{ $value: '123123', $key: 'site1' }, { $value: '0', $key: 'site2' }])
        }, 500);
    })
);

console.log('START');
usersObservable
    .mergeMap((users) => {
        return users.map(user => {
            console.log('found a user ', user);
            return sitesObservable
                .forEach(sites => {
                    sites.forEach(site => {
                        if (site.$value == '123123') {
                            console.log('found site ', site.$key);
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    })
    .first().toPromise().then(x => {
        console.log('ALL DONE')
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

Here is the generated output:

```
START
found a user  {
  "id": 1,
  "$key": 123
}
found site  site1
ALL DONE
```

With your specific firebase code added your Code should look like this:

```
console.log('START');
var siteUsers = this.af.database.list('Sites/-KcF5J9SoSHDrUEYO-Ed/Users');

siteUsers
    .mergeMap(users => {
        console.log('users = ', users);
        return users.map(user => {
            console.log('found a user ', user);
            return this.af.database.list('registeredUsers/' + user.$key + '/Sites')
                .forEach(sites => {
                    console.log('sites = ', sites)
                    sites.forEach(site => {
                        if (site.$value == '-KcF5J9SoSHDrUEYO-Ed') {
                            console.log('found site ', site.$key);
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    })
    .first().toPromise().then(x => {
        console.log('ALL DONE')
    });
```

Comment: i tried that too, the same , its keep getting me the promise after the outer loop only without waiting for the nested to complete

Comment: if you can't get the correct behavior with return statements in the map functions please make sure all `*.database.list(...)` calls return an observable and no simple array

Comment: database.list(..) return FirebaseListObservable<any[]>

Comment: i found the problem, instead of the `map` operator you need to use `mergeMap` on the users listObservable

Comment: i tried the above code with mergeMap, i didn't get the ALL DONE message !!?

Comment: the above sample didnt work too, did u test it on a Firebase ?

Comment: no I didn't test it with a firebase system, thats why I mocked the users and sites Observable in my sample. But as long as the angularFire lib always returns Observables from the list(...) calls this should work as expected. At the moment I am a bit clueless why this is not working and perhaps I have to setup a sample with firebase connected

Answer (score 1):

@Kalle

i tried this way too, also same :

```
 console.log('START');
  var siteUsers = this.af.database.list('Sites/-KcF5J9SoSHDrUEYO-Ed/Users');
  const siteUsersObservable = Observable.from(siteUsers);

  siteUsersObservable
    .map(users => {
      console.log('users = ', users);
      return users.map(user => {
        console.log('found a user ', user);
        var userSites = this.af.database.list('registeredUsers/' + user.$key + '/Sites');
        const userSitesObservable = Observable.from(userSites);
        return userSitesObservable
          .forEach(sites => {
            console.log('sites = ', sites)
            sites.forEach(site => {
              if (site.$value == '-KcF5J9SoSHDrUEYO-Ed') {
                console.log('found site ', site.$key);
              }
            });
          });
      });
    })
    .first().toPromise().then(x => {
      console.log('ALL DONE')
    });
```

and the firebase structure is like this:

[image]

and my result is :

[image]